# google app engine INFO meaning

Tags: google-app-engine

Im testing an appengine application localy and I want to know what the last numbers in the INFO log, mean

INFO     2013-08-30 00:15:12,914 module.py:593] default: "GET /mobile/ HTTP/1.1" 404 154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 = Page not found.

154 = Size of the response content in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Page not found.  In other words, you do not have url mapping to the url "/mobile/".  Check urls.py (for example, in django/python) and or app.yaml, to make sure you tell the app where a request to "/mobile/" should point.  Post parts of your app.yaml, or your code for url mapping, if you need further troubleshooting